# Go through custom type list and return the first object where a certain member starts with letter "x"

Tags: c#, list

this should be easy but I havent quite figured it out yet:

I have a list of my custom type `Mp3ObjectSmall`.
This is basically a list containing mp3s with the URI on the phone, the artist and the song name. This is the type:

```
public class MP3objectSmall
{
    public string SongName { get; set; }
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }
    public string Mp3Uri { get; set; }
}
```

This list contains about 700 items, each with a different song.

Now, for my recycler view, I need to be able to for instance click on the letter "x" in my app and then have a function return an int with first item in above list containing an "x" as a song name.

Even if I had say 100 song names that all begin with the letter "x" I need to just be returned the first item's position.

How do I find the first string of a member of a custom type list that starts with a certain letter?

If anythin is unclear, just comment on it!

Thank you :-)

What I have tried so far:

```
        if (letter != "0") // scroll to top when it is 0, so nothing needs to be done here 
        {
            foreach(MP3objectSmall o in Mp3ObjectSmall)
            {
                if (letter.Equals(o.SongName.StartsWith(letter)))
                {

                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you, but running a company does not neccissarly mean I have to be good at coding.

Comment: So why doesn't that code work? What does it do, and what not?

Comment: Well, it crashes saying that "o" is not set be an instance of reference

Comment: That suggests your collection contains a null reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2). The simple example for your case.

Also, check [Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

```
var list = new List<MP3objectSmall>();
var s1 = new MP3objectSmall { SongName = "abc" };
var s2 = new MP3objectSmall { SongName = "def" };
var s3 = new MP3objectSmall { SongName = "xyz" };
var s4 = new MP3objectSmall { SongName = "xxx" };

list.Add(s1);
list.Add(s2);
list.Add(s3);
list.Add(s4);

var filteredList = list.Where(i => i.SongName.StartsWith("x")).ToList();

foreach(var item in filteredList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.SongName);
}
```

- `list.Where` will filter the list based on the provided condition
- `i => i.SongName` is a lambda expression which allows accessing the object properties.
- `StartsWith`provides a way to find/filter the string which starts with specifi character

Remember to import these namespaces

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

Also, use [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2) as the question is to fetch the first element after filters.

Comment: Hi and thank you. Unfortunately, no matter what letter i put, the list always returns 0 objects

Comment: Could you please update the code with some sample source you're using?

Comment: sorry. you also are right. I confused upper with lowercase letters! :)

Comment: `i => i.SongName.toLowerCase().StartsWith("x")` - no matter what case and you can provide the filter criteria with lower case

Comment: The `filteredList` will hold a `List<MP3objectSmall>` containing both `s3` and `s4` - but that was not what was asked for in the question... If you're going to use `linq`, I think you should just use `FirstOrDefault` with the predicate you have. This will return only the first occurrence or `default(MP3objectSmall)` (which is `null`) if not found.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Ya I agree, but this is just for some basic understanding

Comment: Well obviously the OP is not fluent with linq, otherwise this question wouldn't have been asked in the first place. I think in this case it's better to suggest a solution that actually address the question asked rather then a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindIndex_System_Predicate__0__):

```
var indexOfFirstSongThatStartsWithX = Mp3ObjectSmall
    .FindIndex(s => s.SongName.StartsWith("x"));
```

This will return the index of the first item in the list where the SongName property starts with an `x`.

If you want the item itself, you can use [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2) the same way:

```
var firstSongThatStartsWithX = Mp3ObjectSmall
    .Find(s => s.SongName.StartsWith("x"));
```

This will return the first item where the SongName property starts with an `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `List<>` variable itself.

For example, assumed you have a similar code:

```
var songList = /* some function returning a List object like: List<MP3objectSmall> */;
```

You could then do some List filtering:

```
int desiredIndex = songList.FindIndex(file => file.SongName.StartWith(letter));
```

Your index is then in the variable `desiredIndex`

Comment: `FindIndex` is a method of `List`, there's no linq involved there.

Comment: Oh sorry, this totally worked. There was just confusion with upper and lowercase letters. thanks a lot!

Comment: @ZoharPeled totally right. At first I had some Linq expression there. Forgot to adjust the text. Edited now!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RzH5li

```
public static void Main()
{

    List<MP3objectSmall> songs = new List<MP3objectSmall>();

    songs.Add(new MP3objectSmall(){SongName ="a"});
    songs.Add(new MP3objectSmall(){SongName ="b"});
    songs.Add(new MP3objectSmall(){SongName ="x"});
    songs.Add(new MP3objectSmall(){SongName ="z"});

    string letter = "x";

    MP3objectSmall  firstSong = songs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SongName.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith(letter));

    if(firstSong != null)
    {
        int index = songs.IndexOf(firstSong);
        Console.WriteLine(index);
    }
}
```